# php cURL loop downloads once, then stops

Tags: php, curl, php-ziparchive

The basics of what I'm trying to do is access an API multiple times to download many audio files.

The idea is I have a function called 'download_audio'. This function is a cURL that works for any singular ID i give it. However when I put that same function into a foreach loop, which loops through IDs, it will work once, then stop. I'm curious as to both why it's stopping, and how I can resolve this problem.

notably this a secure server which requires me to get a token before I can access it, that's what the 'JWTtoken' is. Otherwise my code looks like this:

```
function download_audio($JWTtoken, $contactId)
{
    $format = "wav";
    $userArray = array();
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => "https://MYURL/" . $contactId . "/" . $format,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_CAINFO => "../cacert.pem",
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 15,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 1,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
      CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => 6,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "content-type: audio/" . $format, $JWTtoken,
        "Content-Description: File Transfer",
        "Content-Type: audio/" . $format,
        "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $contactId . "." . $format,
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary",
        "Expires: 0",
        "Cache-Control: must-revalidate",
        "Pragma: public"
        )));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) 
    {
          return "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    }
    else
    {
        header("Content-type: application/octet-stream"); 
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $contactId . "." . $format); 
        echo $response;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you put the loop - in the function above or in something that calls this function?

Comment: I'm calling this function in the loop. something like:
    
    foreach( $myarray as $key => $item)
    {
        some logic that gets my ID's from the array
        $DLaudio = download_audio($JWTtoken, $id)
    }

Comment: All those headers you're sending are response headers, not request headers.

Comment: You're sending the response as a download to the client. But you can only send one download at a time.

Comment: Are you being rate limited by the api?

Comment: I do not believe the API is limiting me. I tried removing some of the tags at the top. And it began downloading, and it clearly was attempting to download all the files into one wav file. So I'm thinking I will need to create a zip file for this and download that?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to finally get this working, I am sending just an 'IDarray' which is just an array of ID's into this function, as well as the security token. Effectively the original answer is that you can only download one file per request. I originally thought that because I was calling the function multiple times it would request multiple times. However that's not the case, so I was able to zip all the files into one file, then download that one file.

The below function is working for me:

```
function download_multiaudio_zip($JWTtoken, $IDArray)
{
    //turn ID array into URL array
    foreach ($IDArray as $key => $id)
    {
        $URLArray[$key] = "https://MYURL/downloadaudio/" . $id . "/wav";
    }
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $tmp_file = tempnam('.','');
    $zip->open($tmp_file, ZipArchive::CREATE);
    foreach ($URLArray as $key => $URL)
    {
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
          CURLOPT_URL => $URL,
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
          CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
          CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
          CURLOPT_CAINFO => "../cacert.pem",
          CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 15,
          CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 1,
          CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
          CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => 6,
          CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
          CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
          CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "content-type: audio/wav", $JWTtoken,
            "Content-Description: File Transfer"
            )));
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        $zip->addFromString($IDArray[$key] . ".wav", $response);
    }
    $zip->close();
    if ($err) 
    {
      return "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    }
    else
    {
        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=audiofiles.zip');
        header('Content-type: application/zip');
        readfile($tmp_file);
    }
}
```